# Fonts in Chakra-ui theme not assigned in the configuration

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, chakra-ui, emotion

I know there are similar questions already made before, but nothing really helped me in this. I'm writing an open source app called Cocoso, and have been using Chakra-UI already for 2 years and I love it. I have even successfully used another font.

But I don't know what I did wrong, I cannot figure out why the assigning of font does not work. I checked everything. I can't find.

The current branch where it's working fine is here: https://github.com/eminx/cocoso/blob/474b87d2b48d917af6e1b28a9d9392b5dd73bb7e/imports/ui/utils/constants/theme.js#L4
This is where I consume the theme: https://github.com/eminx/cocoso/blob/develop/imports/ui/LayoutContainer.jsx

And here is the theme new branch where it's not working: https://github.com/eminx/cocoso/blob/sexythumbs/imports/ui/utils/constants/theme.js
This is it's consumed: https://github.com/eminx/cocoso/blob/sexythumbs/imports/ui/LayoutContainer.jsx

The problem must be related to something else than these files because I cannot get it to work even in the simplest scenario of assigning only fonts to the `extendTheme()` function. It is also not about fonts not loading. It doesn't work even with already loaded fonts. It's something else in the code that refrains the configuration to work. And only fonts configuration... Feel free to please check the code of the app for a potential solution proposal.

Help appreciated. Thanks!